# Find the value closest to median in a dataframe

Tags: python

I just pick up python couple months ago and new to this forum. Appreciate if anyone can help.
I want to find the value closest to the median.

1. To get the median for each unit, I am using groupby and median().
2. Then get the difference from the original dataframe
3. Use abs() and idxmin() to get the least delta.
   Basically I end up with another dataframe that has the index of closest value to the median. How do I proceed to use the index to get the actual value?

```
Unit    Test1   Test2   Test3
Unit1   0.254279388 0.010388754 0.820704593
Unit1   0.957139807 0.207681463 0.738428693
Unit1   0.043462803 0.154220478 0.606568744
Unit2   0.044308884 0.134817932 0.697317637
Unit2   0.244895686 0.909262442 0.153881824
Unit3   0.368147792 0.735655648 0.200679595
Unit3   0.30457518  0.929519313 0.823938759
Unit3   0.537633836 0.661168043 0.736937724
Unit3   0.410137495 0.567494043 0.68300754
Unit3   0.525483757 0.556830631 0.988314575
```

to

```
Unit    Test1   Test2   Test3
Unit1   0.254279388 0.154220478 0.738428693
Unit2   0.144602285 0.522040187 0.425599731
Unit3   0.410137495 0.661168043 0.736937724
```

here is the snippet of the code. Each column should have its own index, but iloc uses the first index for all columns

DATA_MEDIAN = DATA.groupby('Unit').median()

DATA_INDEX = (DATA.set_index(['Unit']) -
DATA_MEDIAN).abs().reset_index().groupby('Unit').idxmin()

DATA_INDEX.reset_index(inplace=True)

DATA_CLOSEST = DATA.iloc[DATA_INDEX.index]

Comment: please tell what you have tried. show us some code. thank you

Comment: sorry for miss understanding. I mean use the `edit` in your question and show your code there. in the question body.

Comment: The median of which column? Test1, test2, or test3?

Comment: yes, each Test has its own median by Unit

Comment: You're looking for the value closest to the median - but the median of what, exactly?

Comment: That is, the row closest to the median for unit1 and *test1* might be different than the row closest to the median of *test2* and unit1.

Comment: For example, Unit3 has 5 measurements for each Tests. The result should be the measurement closest to the median of the 5 measurements. This is repeated for each Tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. Please note that for units with only two rows, the choice of the value which is closest to the mean is arbitrary.

```
t = df.melt(id_vars="Unit")
t["distance_from_mean"] = t.groupby(["Unit", "variable"]).transform("mean").subtract(t.value, axis=0).abs()

t = t.loc[t.groupby(["Unit", "variable"], as_index=False)["distance_from_mean"].idxmin()]

res = pd.pivot_table(t, columns="variable", index = "Unit", values="value")
print(res)
```

The output is:

```
variable     Test1     Test2     Test3
Unit                                  
Unit1     0.254279  0.154220  0.738429
Unit2     0.044309  0.134818  0.153882
Unit3     0.410137  0.661168  0.683008
```

---

If some of the units only have NaN values for a given test, the code needs to be slightly modified. See below (with an example of such a dataframe):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Unit": ["Unit1"] * 3 + ["Unit2"] * 2 + ["Unit3"] * 5, 
    "Test1": range(10), 
    "Test2": range(10, 20), 
    "Test3": range(20,30)
})
df.loc[3:4, "Test2"] = np.NaN
print(df)

==>
    Unit  Test1  Test2  Test3
0  Unit1      0   10.0     20
...
3  Unit2      3    NaN     23
4  Unit2      4    NaN     24
5  Unit3      5   15.0     25
...
```

The code you're looking for:

```
t = df.melt(id_vars="Unit")
t["distance_from_mean"] = t.groupby(["Unit", "variable"]).transform("mean").subtract(t.value, axis=0).abs()

indices = t.groupby(["Unit", "variable"], as_index=False)["distance_from_mean"].idxmin()
indices.dropna(inplace = True)

t = t.loc[indices]

res = pd.pivot_table(t, columns="variable", index = "Unit", values="value")
print(res)

==>

variable  Test1  Test2  Test3
Unit                         
Unit1       1.0   11.0   21.0
Unit2       3.0    NaN   23.0
Unit3       7.0   17.0   27.0
```

Comment: Your code only works on the first column (Test1) while the rest (Test2 and Test3) follow the same index.
For example Unit3, I need to find the value closest to the median of the 5 values. This is repeated for each columns (Test1/2/3), so the result for each columns are different.

Comment: Thanks, it should work but I am getting KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported'

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: version 1.0.5. I think the "distance_from_mean" column name was removed after the 2nd groupby. Just need to put it back.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Are you using the exact same data frame as in the question?

Comment: you are right. it works on the original dataset but my other bigger dataset. Does it not work on null value?

Comment: I don't know ... I don't know what are the differences between the sample dataset and the real one.

Comment: See my latest edit. The original code supports NaN values, but not if an entire unit / test is NaN. The new code does support this case. Let me know if it works for you.